# How to make the File Attach option available?

Tags: files

When attaching a file to an instance of a content type, there is an option to use ‘file attach’. 
This is an alternative to uploading a file to the server from one’s local computer. Instead, when creating the content, you click on File attach option and it shows the contents of the folder sites/default/files/file_attach.

but i don’t remember how to get this option to be available! does anyone know?

this is much more efficient than uploading files from my laptop to the server

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the edit page of the content type that contains the file field, there is a  closed pane labelled 'File Attach Setting'. Inside of that is a checkbox that reads 'File attach from server directory'. It needs to be checked.

Also note, regardless of where you've specified that the file be stored, the module will create a dir named file_attach. This confused me earlier. I thought it was looking only for files in the default directory ie
sites/default/files/file_attach